# How can I "cache" a variable in Bash?

Tags: bash, cron

I have a bash script which is run every 10m by `cron`. The script performs an expensive calculation for some value (say variable x=value). I need to "cache" this value for 2-3 hours. What are possible solutions to this problem?

I tried [memcached](http://memcached.org/) but it doesn't seem to play well with bash.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Write a second script that does the actual calculation and saves the result to a file:

```
# calculate $curval
printf '%s' "$curval" > /var/foo/value.txt
```

Schedule it with `cron` to run every 2-3 hours.

In the "every 10 minutes" script, simply read the current value from the file:

```
curval=$(< /var/foo/value.txt)
```

A nice refinement is to call the calculation script from the "every 10 minutes" script if the `value.txt` file doesn't exist yet. You could even make it add the `crontab` entry if it's missing.

Comment: Three issues: You should quote `$curval` to avoid issues with IFS, and you should also use `printf`, as you can't tell what's in the file, so `echo` is unsafe (it could pass any argument to echo). Also, there's no need to invoke the external command `cat` to read a file into a variable when `bash` can do it itself, in the form `$(</var/foo/value.txt)`.

Comment: Yes, all that. :)

Answer (score 1):

I'd agree with writing the result to a file, set the variable in the file

```
curval=the_value
```

Then in the shell (or another script)

```
source current_variable_value_result_file
```

Answer (score 1):

You can store your variables inside a simple plain text file.

I used two bash functions for that:

```bash
# the cache file in /tmp
CACHE_FILE="/tmp/your-file.txt"
touch "$CACHE_FILE"

# Set a cache/key value in your text file us `=` as separator
function set_cache() {
  echo -e "$1=$2" >> "$CACHE_FILE"
}

# grep the key in the cache file and extract the value using awk
function get_cache() {
  grep -F "$1" "$CACHE_FILE" | awk -F"=" '{print $2}'
}
```

It's far from perfect and it doesn't work if your key contains the separator value you choose (here `=`), but it's a good start and it helped me a lot.

I guess a second cron job could remove the cache file periodically.